# Restrict DB table to have only one future dated record

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Our project has a requirement that only one future dated record is allowed on a table. Every tables are maintaining record versions using start date and end date. A sample scenario is attached in below screenshot. (assume today's date is 7-Mar-2019)

[image]

So, how can I restrict database table to have more than one future dated record. Is there any constraints or triggers would help to do the validation from DB itself ?.( I am using MySQL db)

Comment: Any other technologies in play (php,python)?

Comment: Yes. We use Java+Springboot+Mybatis+Mysql combination.

Comment: Just to be clear you are allowed to enter row 6(senior manager) but the end date should be null if there is another future dated end date?

Comment: If future date is null then consider it as 31-Dec-9999. Did I clarify your query.?

Comment: nope, please read my comment again and explain why row 7 doesn't have a date of 31-dec-9999

Comment: End date is not mandatory. If it is null, then system consider it as infinity ( 31-dec-9999 ). but if you create a 8th record similar to 7th record, system wont allow because date overlapping is not allowed. Did I answer now ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way might be to overwrite end dates with null in a trigger for example

```
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t before insert on t
for each row 
begin
    declare cnt int default 0;
    select count(*) into cnt from t where end_date > date(now());
    if cnt > 0 then
        set new.end_date = null;
    end if;
end $$

delimiter ;


insert into t (designation,end_date) values 
('a','2019-03-07'),('a','2019-03-07'),('a','2019-04-07'),('a','2019-04-07'),
('b','2019-04-07');

select * from t;

+----+-------------+------------+
| id | designation | end_date   |
+----+-------------+------------+
|  1 | a           | 2019-03-07 |
|  2 | a           | 2019-03-07 |
|  3 | a           | 2019-04-07 |
|  4 | a           | NULL       |
|  5 | b           | NULL       |
+----+-------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You could tweak the code a bit by using an if exists test if you prefer.